# "Підіймати" vs "піднімати". Звідки два слова?

Tags: етимологія, різниця-між-словами, вибір-слова

1. Словопедія:
   http://slovopedia.org.ua/49/53407/359844.html

У всіх прикладах і один, і інший варіант.

2. СУМ:
   http://sum.in.ua/s/pidnimaty

Те саме.

3. Офіційний сайт української мови: [https://ukrainskamova.com/search/](https://ukrainskamova.com/search/?q=%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8&t=0)

Взагалі вважає їх синонімами.

Чому так? Це просто два слова, які в українській мові завжди існували паралельно, чи є якась конкретна причина, чому такі схожі слова мають одне й те саме значення і вважаються взаємозамінними?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Є давноруський корінь (присутній, наприклад, у праслов'янских **jьmǫ*, **jęti*), що в сучасних словах може приймати доволі різні форми:

- -(й)м-: мати, виймати, відіймати, діймати, займ (-ати, -аний), найм (-ати, -аний, -ит, -ичка), обійми (-ати), пере́йми (-атися), підіймати, піймати, при́йми (-ати);
- -єм-: ємкий (-ність, -нісний), виємний, від'ємний, взаємний, об'єм, приємний, роз'єм;
- -їм-: виїмка (-ок, -частий);
- -йом-: зйомка, найомний, підйом, прийом;
- -нім-: віднімати, знімати, піднімати, рознімати;
- -(й)н-: йняти, виняток (вийняти), відняти, дійняти, зайняти, зняти, найняти, обійняти, підняти (підійняти), перейняти, прийняти, розняти.

Це все однокорінні слова (навіть якщо в сучасній морфології їх не розглядають як однокорінні, етимологічно вони з одного коріння). В інших слов'янських мовах є подібні корені / виявлення одного кореня (наприклад: [у російській мові](//ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD:%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2:%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C) (натиснути «показать» справа)) — хоча в різних мовах міра представлення різних варіантів може бути різною (зокрема дехто вважає, що ряд *-йом-* в українській мові [має бути коротшим](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/1264) або [повністю прибраним](http://r2u.org.ua/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=7385&p=27943#p27945)).

*Під-* — не єдиний префікс, що присутній одночасно в декількох рядах. У деяких випадках різні варіанти кореня при якомусь префіксі дають одне й те саме значення (наприклад: [*відіймати* і *віднімати*](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=13198&page=432)), в деяких випадках набувають трохи різних конотацій (наприклад: *приймати* і *прийняти* — недоконане і доконане), а в деяких — істотно відрізняються за значенням (наприклад: *[обі́йми](http://sum.in.ua/s/obijmy)* і *[об'є́ми](http://sum.in.ua/s/ob.jem)*, *[при́йми](http://sum.in.ua/s/pryjmy)* і *[прийо́ми](http://sum.in.ua/s/pryjom)*). Причому при повному збігу значень декількох де-факто наявних варіантів іноді лише один з них визнається літературним (наприклад: *[розіймати](//www.google.com/search?q=%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8)* і *[рознімати](http://sum.in.ua/s/roznimaty)*), а іноді — декілька (наприклад: [*відіймати* і *віднімати*](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=13198&page=432), [*підіймати* і *піднімати*](http://sum.in.ua/s/pidnimaty)).

<sub>P.S.: Того ж походження деякі слова з *-дій-*: діймати/дійняти, *здіймати/здійняти*, (рідковживане) *[роздіймати/роздійняти](http://sum.in.ua/s/roznimaty)*. Хоча комусь може здаватися, що *-дій-* у них є коренем (як в *дія*, *діяти*, *діяльність*) — але «Етимологічний словник української мови» О. Мельнчука (том 2, ст. 296–297, «іма́ти») та інші джерела (В. Науменко, «Обзор фонетических особенностей малорусской рѣчи», [ст. 77](//books.google.com/books?id=kshHAQAAMAAJ&q=%22%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8,+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5+%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8A+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%B8,+%D1%82.+%D0%B5.+%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE+%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0+%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%8A-%D0%B1%D1%8B+%D0%BF%D0%BE+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%86%D1%83+%D0%BFi%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8+(%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8A-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BFi%D0%B4%D1%96-%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8)")) визначають етимологію, згідно з якою коренем виявляється таки *-йм-/-йн-*. А от, наприклад, *знайти* (хоча комусь може спа́сти на думку, що *-й-* там є залишком старого *-йм-*) — це вже інші похождення (від *найти* від *йти* від **jьdǫ*) і корінь (*-йт-*).</sub>

Comment: Дякую за відповідь. Тобто, був один корінь, а стало декілька? І деякі з новоутворених синонімічні - от і все?

Comment: @P.Vovk, саме так.

Comment: А що значить "натиснути «показать» справа"?